# How to Remove Object From Array Where Property Equals Null - Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects like so:

```
var a = [

  {
    "ClientSideAction": 1,
    "CompletedDate": "not null",
    "ItemDescription": "Step 1"
  },
  {
    "ClientSideAction": 1,
    "CompletedDate": null,
    "ItemDescription": "step 2"
  },
  {
    "ClientSideAction": 1,
    "CompletedDate": "not null",
    "ItemDescription": "Step 3"
  },
  {
    "ClientSideAction": 1,
    "CompletedDate": null,
    "ItemDescription": "step 4"
  }

];
```

How would I remove the elements where `CompletedDate == null`?

I've tried `._dropWhile`, however it stops as soon as the function returns falsey which isn't what I want. I want to loop through all objects and remove those that match that condition. Now, I know that I can use regular js for this, but I'd like to use lodash if possible. I'm a beginner in Lodash and I'm trying to get better.

This was the .dropWhile I used:

```
var a2 = _.dropWhile(a, function(o) { return o.CompletedDate == null; });
```

Comment: Please show your code that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the native `Array.filter()` to filter items out.

```js
var a = [
  {
    "ClientSideAction": 1,
    "CompletedDate": "not null",
    "ItemDescription": "Step 1"
  },
  {
    "ClientSideAction": 1,
    "CompletedDate": null,
    "ItemDescription": "step 4"
  }
];

var b = a.filter(function(item) {
  return item.CompletedDate !== null;
});

console.log(b);
```

This can be further simplified in modern browsers or nodejs using arrow functions:

```
var b = filter((x => x.CompletedDate !== null);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of lodash just filter

```
var res = a.filter(x => x.CompletedDate !== null);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP meant that every `CompletedDate` that isn't null is a string, not a literal string saying `"not null"`.

Comment: You are probably right, but in that case why not just ommit the field in declaration ?

Comment: They may not be declaring it, it could be pulled from an API. That, or their implementation may depend on the field existing, null or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var a = [

  {
    "ClientSideAction": 1,
    "CompletedDate": "not null",
    "ItemDescription": "Step 1"
  },
  {
    "ClientSideAction": 1,
    "CompletedDate": null,
    "ItemDescription": "step 2"
  },
  {
    "ClientSideAction": 1,
    "CompletedDate": "not null",
    "ItemDescription": "Step 3"
  },
  {
    "ClientSideAction": 1,
    "CompletedDate": null,
    "ItemDescription": "step 4"
  }
];

var a = a.filter(function(v) {
  return v.CompletedDate != null;
})

console.log(a)
```